# Ayuda con Los state en react native

Tags: react-native

[image]
necesito dale me gusta a un solo articulo en esta lista pero cuando le doy like todas se marcan como que seleccione todas las publicaciones como puedo hacer para solucionar este problema ? solo quiero darle me gusta a una sola publicacion con state

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Revisa el documento [ask], esta pregunta no tiene un formato correcto ni la información necesaria para ser respondida, cual es el código que has intentado.

Comment: Necesitas poner el código que usas para iterar las publicaciones y el método que usas para indicar que una te gusta.